# How do I call inner classes from execute anonymous or another class

Tags: apex, class, inner-class

When I try to call this from execute anonymous it fails and says
"Type is not visible: OutterClass.InnerClass
"

`OutterClass.InnerClass inresponse = new OutterClass.InnerClass(); System.debug(inresponse.name);`

```
public class OutterClass {
    Public String name = 'outterclass';
    
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    class InnerClass{
        String name = 'innerclass';
    }

}
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't specify an access modifier for the inner class, the default one (private) has been used, as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining.htm):

> The `private` access modifier declares that this class is only known locally, that is, only by this section of code. This is the default access for inner classes—that is, if you don't specify an access modifier for an inner class, it is considered `private`. This keyword can only be used with inner classes (or with top level test classes marked with the `@isTest` annotation).

In order to create an instance of the inner class you have to declare it `public`.
Just change `class InnerClass {` to `public class InnerClass {`.

By the way, also the `name` property is not accesible, so you have to declare it `public` too.

```
public class OutterClass {
    Public String name = 'outterclass';
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public class InnerClass{
        public String name = 'innerclass';
    }
}
```